# Most recent post is missing from Author page

Tags: author, recent-posts, author-template

Here is the loop from my `author.php` page. It is showing recent posts, but not the MOST recent.

Where is my mistake?

```
    <?php if (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <h3>
            <?php _e('All posts by'); ?> <?php echo get_the_author(); ?>
            <span class="arrows">&raquo;</span>
        </h3>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="cat-post">
    <div class="cat-post-left">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?> - <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( '300x169' ); ?></a>
        <div class="meta-box">
        <div class="post-meta">
<div class="line"><cite>By &nbsp;<span class="plus-icon"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span></cite><span><?php the_date(); ?></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?> - <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <a class="continue-reading" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read on &raquo;</a>
            </div>
```

[Here is the site](http://crowncrazed.com). The "Editor's Pick" post on the homepage is the most recent and does not show up on [the Author page.](http://crowncrazed.com/author/tpflanz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in your first block of code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <h3>
        <?php _e('All posts by'); ?> <?php echo get_the_author(); ?>
        <span class="arrows">&raquo;</span>
    </h3>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
```

You call `the_post()` to populate the regular template tags (i.e. `get_the_author()`) but don't use the rest of the post.  Then, inside your `while` loop, you call `the_post()` to populate these template tags with the *next* post in the result set.

Instead, you need to handle the first post in that first block as well.  Change your code to something like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <h3>
        <?php _e('All posts by'); ?> <?php the_author(); ?>
        <span class="arrows">&raquo;</span>
    </h3>

    <!-- markup for first post -->
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="cat-post">
        <div class="cat-post-left">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?> - <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( '300x169' ); ?></a>
            <div class="meta-box">
                <div class="post-meta">
                    <div class="line"><cite>By &nbsp;<span class="plus-icon"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span></cite><span><?php the_date(); ?></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?> - <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <a class="continue-reading" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read on &raquo;</a>
    </div>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>

    <!-- markup for subsequent posts -->
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="cat-post">
        <div class="cat-post-left">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?> - <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( '300x169' ); ?></a>
            <div class="meta-box">
                <div class="post-meta">
                    <div class="line"><cite>By &nbsp;<span class="plus-icon"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span></cite><span><?php the_date(); ?></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?> - <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <a class="continue-reading" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read on &raquo;</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be better handled with using `rewind_posts();`. I've used this to get around this problem recently, and it's worked well. It simply rewinds the loop back to the first post (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts).

I've suggested (untested) code below.

```
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <h3>
        <?php _e('All posts by'); ?> <?php echo get_the_author(); ?>
        <span class="arrows">&raquo;</span>
    </h3>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="cat-post">
<div class="cat-post-left">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?> - <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( '300x169' ); ?></a>
    <div class="meta-box">
    <div class="post-meta">
<div class="line"><cite>By &nbsp;<span class="plus-icon"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span></cite><span><?php the_date(); ?></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?> - <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <a class="continue-reading" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read on &raquo;</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer, it provides a much better/cleaner solution.